# Can't display request.body in server log?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm new to Node and I can't seem to get my request to complete. I'm just trying to create a basic handshake between server and client by sending the location for the client to the server and displaying that into the server log. I'm not sure why I can't display the data into the log.

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening at 8080'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));

app.post('/api',(request,response) => {
    console.log('I got a request!');
console.log(request.body);
});
```

Index.html

```
 <script>
        if('geolocation' in navigator) {
            console.log('geolocation is avaliable');
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
                const lat = position.coords.latitude;
                const lon = position.coords.longitude;

                console.log(lat,lon);
                document.getElementById('latitude').textContent = lat;
                document.getElementById('longitude').textContent = lon;

                const data = {lat, lon};
                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    header:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                };
                fetch('/api',options);
            });
        } else{
            console.log('geolocation is not avaliable');
        }
    </script>
```

Some things to note. The request does seem to complete and no errors are shown in the developer console.

Server information:
-[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

-[nodemon] starting node index.js

-listening at 8080

-I got a request!

-{}

Comment: have you tried to stringify the request body?

Comment: how would I go about that?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(request.body)`

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: request is not defined` is the error I get as a response

Comment: @Harsh what version of express? Same one you got that example from?

Comment: 4.17.1 - I believe, it is the newest version which I think is the same one the Coding Train uses. Edit- It is 4.17.1, I just confirmed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `index.js`:

```
npm i -S body-parser
```

```js
// Takes the raw requests and turns them into usable properties on req.body
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

```js
app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
  console.log('I got a request!');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body));
});
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, so do you want me to use this in conjunction with `JSON.stringify(request.body) `? If not, I get `ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined` as an error

Comment: @Harsh updated post and yes depending on what you're trying to console log you'll have to stringify.

Comment: Followed the edit, I got a few more errors. Here they are if it help - npm ERR! code E404 |
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bodyParser - Not found |
npm ERR! 404  'bodyParser@latest' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: @Harsh had the wrong spelling for package `body-parser`

Comment: The package successfully installed but the prior error is still there.

Comment: @Harsh did you require it into the file?

Comment: @Harsh at the top of `index.js` add this `const bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

Comment: Ok, it seems like we are back at ground zero. Same issue as before - it say it has received a request but nothing in the `{ }`

Comment: @Harsh are you getting a 200 in network tab? also try to not stringify in frontend

Comment: Under status:304 as for not stringifying in front end - that didn't work either

Comment: try restarting your node service, seems like a caching issue. then check network tab again for status

Comment: So I did a node and then pc restart and nothing changed unfortunately

Comment: lets try this, [express-generator-api](https://github.com/pietgeursen/generator-api) install and follow instructions in the repo. Update frontend endpoint accordingly and see if its local to your setup

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try tomorrow. Got something going on now so we'll see if that works. Thanks for the help thusfar

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in your index.js

```
    const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET')
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: It tells me `clean exit - waiting for changes before restart` in nodemon